# removing index.php from home page url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to remove index.php from home page URL

```
example.com/index.php
```

to

```
example.com
```

and

```
example.com/directory/index.php
```

to

```
example.com/directory
```

I read many posts on stackoverflow and when I'm using those codes then if I go to an invalid URL (like - **example.com/ahjgbhjkllghfd**) then it will not showing 404 response. it shows response 200 and main page content on the invalid URL.

{ sorry for bad English :) }

Comment: Could you please do let me know if this has helped you in my answer's comments section?

Answer (score 2):

If you need 404 error response then try adding [ErrorDocument](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html) line

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

It will show `/error.php` file when `/ahjgbhjkllghfd` is accessed.

All together might be this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,NC]

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, have written on mobile couldn't test it should work I believe.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(.*/?)index\.php/?$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: You can remove `RewriteCond` since there won't be a directory with the name `index.php`